# check for the following node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've a small question in XSLT. i need XPath to validate a condition. and below is my XML.

```
<root>
<para>
    Erlanger and several associates formed a syndicate to acquire the lease of an island in the West Indies for &#x00A3;55,000. The idea was to mine the <page num="44"/>island for phosphates. 
</para>
<para>
    <content-style font-style="bold">2.25</content-style> A commission or payment that a promoter receives upon transfer of property to a company must also be disclosed.
        <para>
            board were all nominees of Green and Smith; <page num="45"/>accordingly, disclosure   </para>
</para>
<para>
    <content-style font-style="bold">2.26</content-style> If a promoter contracts with the company whether as vendor<footnote num="57" id="fn57">
        <para>
            <case>
                <casename>
                    <content-style font-style="italic">Re Leeds &#x0026; Hanley Theatres of Varieties Ltd</content-style>
                </casename> &#x005B;1902&#x005D; Ch 809 (Court of Appeal, England)
            </case>.
        </para>
    </footnote> or purchaser,<footnote num="58" id="fn58">
        <para>
            <case>
                <casename>
                    <content-style font-style="italic">Habib Abdul Rahman v Abdul Cader</content-style>
                </casename> (1886) 4 Ky 193 (High Court of the Straits Settlements)
            </case>.
        </para>
    </footnote> the fact that he is a contractor must be disclosed.
</para>
</root>
```

and XSL is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:variable name="ThisDocument" select="document('')"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html>]]></xsl:text>

        <html>
            <head>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</meta>]]></xsl:text>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="chapter/title[1]/*"/>
                </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\SG\Commentary_SG_XML-03032014\SG-Business Guide to Competition Law\05192014\XSLT\main.css" type="text/css"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</link>]]></xsl:text>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:if test="//footnote">
                    <section class="tr_footnotes">
                        <hr/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//page[not(ancestor::toc)]| //footnote" mode="footnote"/>

                    </section>
                </xsl:if>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <xsl:variable name="varHeaderNote" select='concat("f",@num)'/>
        <xsl:variable name="varFootNote" select='concat("#ftn.",@num)'/>
        <sup>
            <a name="{$varHeaderNote}" href="{$varFootNote}" class="tr_ftn">
                <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
            </a>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="page" mode="footnote">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote" mode="footnote">

        <div class="tr_footnote">
            <div class="footnote">
                <sup>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>ftn.</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:text>#f</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                    </a>
                </sup>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

here when i run this, i get both `<?pb label='44'?><?pb label='45'?>`

where as i need as condition as below.

```
there should only be a `footnote` following `page` and there should be no `page` between `page` and `footnote`
```

in simple, by taking the above example, there are two `page`, by ignoring all other tags and considering only `page` the structure looks like below.

```
page num='44'
page num='45'
footnote
```

here i want only `page num='45'` to be captured and leave `page num='44'` since `page num='44'` is followed by another `page` but not directly `footnote`, this is pretty confusing, please let me know how can i do this.

The demo can be found [here](http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbt/1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you match a `page` you can check whether the *next* footnote has a preceding page which is the *current* page. If it's not, then you don't print out its processing instruction since it's a page without a footnote.

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="footnote">
    <xsl:if test="following::footnote[1][preceding::page[1]/@num = current()/@num]">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

See: http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbt/3

Answer (score 2):

To capture only pages that contain at least one footnote, you could use a test like

```
(following::page | following::footnote)[1][self::footnote]
```

i.e. take all the following `page` and `footnote` elements in document order, and check whether the first one of these elements is a `footnote` - if it isn't then either there's an intervening `page` or there are no more `page` or `footnote` elements at all, either way we know there are no footnotes on this page.

```
<xsl:template match="page[(following::page | following::footnote)[1][self::footnote]]" mode="footnote">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page" mode="footnote" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> in simple, by taking the above example, there are two `page`, by
>   ignoring all other tags and considering only `page` the structure
>   looks like below.
>
> ```
> page num='44'
> page num='45'
> footnote
> ```
>
> here i want only `page num='45'` to be captured and leave `page
>   num='44'` since `page num='44'` is followed by another `page` but not
>   directly `footnote`

To select pages that are immediately followed by a footnote, use:

```
page[following-sibling::*[1][self::footnote]]
```

If a footnote is always preceded by a page, you could also use:

```
footnote/preceding-sibling::page[1]
```

---

### Edit:

In your **real** example, where pages and footnotes are **not** siblings, you should use Ian's answer, i.e :

```
page[(following::page | following::footnote)[1][self::footnote]]
```

or (assuming that there is only block of footnotes):

```
footnote[1]/preceding::page[1]
```

Comment: That won't help in this example because the `page` elements aren't siblings of the `footnote` elements at all - page 45 is an empty element inside the second `para`, the first footnote is inside the following `para`.

Comment: @IanRoberts "This example" != "the above example".